# What does "deal" and "take " person mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

E.g. when somebody say something like:

Person 1: "Jeana can deal but not take."

Person 2: "Yes, she always was the deal but not take person.﻿"

Could somebody explain to me what "deal" and "take" person mean?

Comment: Can you give more context? Without context, it sounds as if they are talking about work. Perhaps Jeanna is a person who can deal with the work, but cannot take charge of the work.

Comment: I would interpret it the same way as jwpat7 does, but I also think it sounds a little strange.

Comment: Agreed. *Deal with criticism* and *take criticism* really make sense.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh, I was thinking *deal **out** criticism*.  See [*deal out*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/deal-out_1) in Macmillan, sense two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, it looks like *deal* and *take* are being used in the same way that *dish out* and *take* are used in the following example (from wiktionary's *[dish out](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dish_out)* entry):

> She can dish out criticism but she can't take it.

Just what it is that's being dealt or taken depends on context, but common examples include criticism, orders, and unsolicited advice.